# PHP: is $this->something->($this->foo)->bar legal?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is this line legal PHP?

```
$this->mongo->($this->db)->$collection_name->insert($document_name);
```

if $this->db is a constant with the db name to use.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, strings (and thus your constant) should be wrapped in brackets, like this:

```
$this->mongo->{$this->db}->$collection_name->insert($document_name);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
$this->mongo->{$this->db}->$collection_name->insert($document_name);
```

Or assigning `$this->db` to a local var and using that instead:

```
$db_name = $this->db;
$this->mongo->$db_name->$collection_name->insert($document_name);
```

Comment: great! will add as a solution once stack overflow will allow me. option two is bad style. and MongoDB is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

`$connection->db->collection` is just shorthand for:

```
$this->mongo->selectDB($this->db)->selectCollection($collection_name)->insert(...);
```

which might work better in your case.  +1 for BoltClock's answer, too, though, if you want stick with the `$x->y->z` style.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not have ->()-> where you have mongo->($this->db)->$coll...
Maybe you were looking for

```
$this->mongo($this->db)->$collection_name->insert($document_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted `$this->mongo->selectDB($this->db)->$collection_name->insert($document_name)`